# Is a deterministic path a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a question about what classifies as a Markov chain and what does not. Consider a system with state space $\left\{ 1,\ldots,n \right\}$ and a trajectory for the system defined by the following transition matrix
$$P_{ij} = 1 \mathrm{ \ if \ } j = i+1$$
$$P_{n1} = 1$$
This is just a cycle over the n states of the system. Given the initial state of the system, it is clearly a deterministic process. Can this be called a first order time-homogenous Markov chain? If not, is there something in the definition of a Markov chain (besides the fact that it is a random process) based on which it can be shown that this process is not Markov?

Maybe I'm missing out something obvious, but I can't seem to find an answer to my query. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is a Markov chain.  Intuitively, it certainly doesn't have any memory!  Try verifying whatever definition of Markov chain that you are using.

Comment: I don't believe *deterministic* is the correct term here. If $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is the chain and $\nu$ is the initial distribution, can you tell me deterministically what is $X_1$, say? You can say $P(X_1 = i) = [\nu P]_{i}$ (the $i$th element of the vector $\nu P$), but this is a probabilistic (random) answer.

Comment: @Tom If I know $X_0 \in \left\{ 1, \ldots, n \right\}$, then I can exactly determine $X_1, X_2, ...$. So I believe it is deterministic.

Comment: "Intuitively, it certainly doesn't have any memory!" Rigorously, it does have a memory, which is exactly one-step long.

Answer (score 1):

I would write down that proof.

one want to check that property :

$$ P(x_n = j | x_{k} = i_k : \forall k \in \{0...n-1\} ) = P(x_n = j | x_{n-1} = i_{n-1} ) $$

One can check that writing LHS :

$$P(x_n = i_n | x_{k} = i_k : \forall k \in \{0...n-1\} ) = \frac{P(x_{k} = i_k : \forall k \in \{0...n\} )}{ P(x_{k} = i_k : \forall k \in \{0...n-1\} )}$$

RHS :
$$P(x_n = j | x_{n-1} = i_{n-1} ) = \frac{P(x_n = j, x_{n-1} = i_{n-1} )}{P(x_{n-1} = i_{n-1} )} $$

that when the $i_k$ are well chosen, both probabilities are equal to $1$, otherwise the probability is basically $0$ :)